# Angular production build with localize

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When building production build with localize option, the locale-specific configuration is being ignored.
For example when I specify a different index.html in config for "ar" and build using `ng build --prod --localize=true` the default index.html gets built

Any idea if there is way to perform this with building separatly for each locale?

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ClientApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "file-saver",
              "lodash/cloneDeep",
              "lodash",
              "xlsx",
              "formiojs",
              "kendo-ui-core/js/kendo.datepicker",
              "@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.upload"
            ],
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "src/root/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
            "localize": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "50mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": false,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "dev-fr": {
              "localize": [
                "fr"
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/i18n/messages.ts",
                  "with": "src/i18n/messages.fr.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "fr": {
              "localize": [
                "fr"
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/i18n/messages.ts",
                  "with": "src/i18n/messages.fr.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "hy": {
              "localize": [
                "hy"
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/i18n/messages.ts",
                  "with": "src/i18n/messages.hy.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "ar": {
              "index": "src/index.ar.html",
              "styles": [
                "./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
                "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
                "src/styles/styles.scss",
                "src/assets/css/bootstrap-rtl.css"
              ],
              "localize": [
                "ar"
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/i18n/messages.ts",
                  "with": "src/i18n/messages.ar.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production-fr": {
              "localize": [
                "fr"
              ],
              "outputPath": "dist",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/i18n/messages.ts",
                  "with": "src/i18n/messages.fr.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "50mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "liveReload": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:dev",
              "port": 4321
            },
            "dev-fr": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:dev-fr",
              "port": 4321
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:production"
            },
            "fr": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:fr"
            },
            "hy": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:hy"
            },
            "ar": {
              "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build:ar"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ClientApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "xliffmerge": {
          "builder": "@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling:xliffmerge",
          "options": {
            "xliffmergeOptions": {
              "i18nFormat": "xlf2",
              "srcDir": "src/i18n",
              "genDir": "src/i18n",
              "defaultLanguage": "en",
              "removeUnusedIds": false,
              "allowIdChange": true,
              "beautifyOutput": true,
              "languages": [
                "en",
                "fr",
                "hy",
                "ar"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": {
          "code": "en",
          "baseHref": "/"
        },
        "locales": {
          "fr": {
            "translation": "src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/fr/"
          },
          "hy": {
            "translation": "src/i18n/messages.hy.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/hy/"
          },
          "ar": {
            "translation": "src/i18n/messages.ar.xlf",
            "baseHref": "/ar/"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ClientApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ClientApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng build --prod --localize=true`  does not build a configuration per language. It will only build production config and cater for the translations.

I ended up building for each language separately as follows:

`"scripts": { "build-prod": "npm-run-all bp-*", "bp-en": "ng build --prod  --configuration=en", "bp-fr": "ng build --prod --configuration=fr --delete-output-path=false", "bp-hy": "ng build --prod --configuration=hy --delete-output-path=false", "bp-ar": "ng build --prod --configuration=ar --delete-output-path=false" }`

used npm-run-all package to run all together.

To modify index.html for arabic, the following was used:

`"index": { "input": "src/index.ar.html", "output": "index.html }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"index": {
  "input": "src/index.ar.html",
  "output": "index.html
}
```

Comment: Thank you however that solves only part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below command
"**ng build --localize**"